# Java Input.run error

Tags: java, runtime-error

Alright I'm trying to make a simple multiplayer game in Java. I've written the server and client. I can connect to the server successfully but after a second I get a error that disconnects me.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1769152617
    at Client.updateCordinates(Client.java:49)
    at Input.run(Client.java:143)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The above is the error I receive from the client.
No error is displayed with the server.

**Client side code:**

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Client extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Socket socket;
    static DataInputStream in;
    static DataOutputStream out;
    int playerid;

    int[] x = new int [10];
    int[] y = new int [10];

    boolean left,down,right,up;

    int playerx;
    int playery;
    public void init(){
        setSize(100,100);
        addKeyListener(this);
        try{
        System.out.println("Connecting...");
        socket = new Socket("localhost",7777);
        System.out.println("Connection successful.");
        in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        playerid = in.readInt();
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        Input input = new Input(in,this);
        Thread thread = new Thread(input);
        thread.start();
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(this);
        thread2.start();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Unable to start client");
    }
    }
    public void updateCordinates(int pid, int x2, int y2){
        this.x[pid] = x2;
        this.y[pid] = y2;

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        for (int i=0; i <10;i++){
        g.drawOval(x[i], y[i], 5, 5);
    }

    }
    public void run(){
            while(true){
                if(right == true){
                    playerx += 10;

                }
                if(left == true){
                    playerx -= 10;

                }
                if(up == true){
                    playery += 10;

                }
                if(down == true){
                    playery -= 10;

                }
                if(right||left||up||down){
                    try{
                    out.writeInt(playerid);
                    out.writeInt(playerx);
                    out.writeInt(playery);
                }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error sending cordinates");

                }
                }
                repaint();
                try{
                Thread.sleep(400);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            }
        }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if (e.getKeyCode() == 37){
                left = true;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == 38){
                up = true;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == 39){
                right = true;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == 40){
                down = true;
            }

        }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
             if (e.getKeyCode() == 37){
                left = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == 38){
                up = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == 39){
                right = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == 40){
                down = false;
            }

        }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

        }
}

class Input implements Runnable{
    DataInputStream in;
    Client client;
    public Input(DataInputStream in, Client c){
        this.in = in;
        this.client = c;
    }
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try {
                int playerid = in.readInt();
                int x = in.readInt();
                int y = in.readInt();
                client.updateCordinates(playerid, x, y);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

    }
}
```

**Server Side Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

   static ServerSocket serverSocket;
   static Socket socket;
   static DataOutputStream out;
   static Users[] user = new Users[10];
   static DataInputStream in;
   public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception{
       System.out.println("Starting server");
       serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7777);
       System.out.println("Server Started");
       socket = serverSocket.accept();
       for (int i=0; i <10;i++){
       System.out.println("Connection from:"+socket.getInetAddress());
       out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
       out.writeUTF("This is a of Java sockets");
       System.out.println("Data has been sent.");
       in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
       if(user[i]==null){
           user[i] = new Users(out,in,user,i);
       Thread th = new Thread(user[i]);
       th.start();
       break;

    }
    }
    }
}
class Users implements Runnable{
    DataOutputStream out;
    DataInputStream in;
    Users[]user=new Users[10];
    String name;
    int playerid;
    int playeridin;
    int xin;
    int yin;
    public Users(DataOutputStream out, DataInputStream in, Users[] user, int pid){
       this.out = out;
       this.in = in;
       this.user = user;
       this.playerid = pid;

}
public void run(){
    try {
        out.writeInt(playerid);
    }catch (IOException e1){
        System.out.println("Failed to send PlayerID");
    }
    while(true){
        try{
            playeridin = in.readInt();
            xin = in.readInt();
            yin = in.readInt();
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                if (user[i] !=null){
                    user[i].out.writeInt(playeridin);
                    user[i].out.writeInt(xin);
                    user[i].out.writeInt(yin);
        }
    }
}
    catch(IOException e){
        user[playerid] = null;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: post your complete stack trace

Comment: That's it besides two lines that are Connecting...
Connection successful.

Comment: In the server side inside the for loop you do this `out.writeUTF("This is a of Java sockets");` while on the client side you do this `playerid = in.readInt();` since it is not getting any integer it is reading a random value which is >10

Comment: Okay it's finally not giving me that error but only one client can connect to the server.

Comment: that is a different problem post another question. try with this `new ServerSocket(7777,10);` means 10 clients can connect to server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
 int[] x = new int [10];
```

means the size of x[] is 10 
when you refer this.x[pid] **what is the value of pid?**

If it is **10 or >10** you'll get the exception because the indexes starts from 0
In your case it is from **0 to 9**

Also

In the server side inside the for loop you do this `out.writeUTF("This is a of Java sockets");` while on the client side you do this `playerid = in.readInt();` since it is not getting any integer it is reading a random value which is >10

Comment: Try running the server and client and the error will occur immediately.

Comment: what inputs are you giving?

Comment: I'm not really sure what's happening so the exact input I'm giving I don't know. It would clear up a lot of confusion if you'd run both the scripts and saw what happened for yourself.

Comment: @NoahR : you are creating thread of input which is getting the value from server side. you should put a valid input on server side. Also you should run the server first and then the client

Comment: I am running the server first. The error is still caused. Also what do you mean by a valid input on server side? Could you show me by editing my code above for the server and me looking at what you mean? Also will adding this valid input to the server fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Noah, can you give the sample input values which your entered,which triggered the above exception .because as the exception it self says , it crashed in updatecoordinated(....) functions when there was a array index value which was going out of bound (which in your case might be beyond index 9,since array size of x[] and y[] is 10)

Comment: Run the server and client and the error will occur without me inputting anything.

Comment: @NoahR : the if clause within main function in server class contains break statement,which serves no purpose,since it is going to just break out of just if clause.i wonder if u had noticed it,there is no statement in the if clause which u want skip upon truggering break keyword.